# R package creation: Confused about how to handle text data

Tags: r, package

I am currently creating my first R package and I am getting confused with the way to handle text data.
I've well understood that datasets have to be placed in the ./data subdirectory, saved into one of the .rda, .txt or .csv format, and then can be loaded with the `data()` function.

However, the `data()` function is the same as the `read.table()` function, that is to say it reads the text file (.txt or .csv) and loads it into a data.frame.
That is not what I want : I just want to access to my text file (.txt or .csv) and load it with my own reading function that I developped in my R source code of the package. (it's a special reading function with special checks according to what the package expects).

After reading plenty of topics on the web, I found the system.file() function useful and used it in this way, in my test file:

```
current_dir=system.file(package="MYPACKAGE")
myTextFile=paste(current_dir,"/data/myTextFile.csv",sep="")
# Then I use my own function to load it:
myOwnReadingFunction(myTextFile)
```

This worked fine and my `R CMD check` went well.... Until I follow the advise of the `R CMD check` log:

> "Note: significantly better compression could be obtained by using R
>   CMD build --resave-data"

Tiping `R CMD build --resave-data` before `R CMD check` moves my .csv files into .csv.bz2 and .csv.xz!
So that what I wrote in my test file (see above) now does not work.

Of course I guess I could, for example, change it by:

```
myTextFile=paste(current_dir,"/data/myTextFile.csv.bz2",sep="")
```

But I really wonder if this is the good way to handle text files in a R package. This seems to me a little "tricky".
Is this a "good practice"? 
Isn't another way to simply access to text files without loading it? Have someone already had the same situation?

Bonus question: why doesn't `R CMD build --resave data` use the same compression for my two .csv files? (that is: .bz2 and .xz)

Comment: I don't think you can compress a file and keep it as raw text. Note also that you get a `Note`, not a `warning` or `error`...

Comment: In fact, I also have some .rda files in my ./data subdirectory. You may be right and the note may only be for these .rda files, but how to choose the files to be concerned by the --resave-data option ?
Whatsmore, although the sentence begins with the word "Note", it is shown as a WARNING :* checking data for ASCII and uncompressed saves ... WARNING

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Datasets you place in the `data` folder will be available to the user through the `data()` function, which is designed to only load data with `load()` or `read.table()`. If you wish to include other non-standard files in you R package, place them in the `inst` directory and they will appear in the root of your package once installed and retrievable with `system.file()`.

In other words, your directory structure should look like this prior to packing and checking:

> ```
> MyPackage/data
> MyPackage/inst/extdata   <-- Your data
> MyPackage/man
> MyPackage/R
> ...
> ```

and like this after installation

> ```
> MyPackage/data
> MyPackage/extdata   <-- Your data
> MyPackage/man
> MyPackage/R
> ...
> ```

Your files can now be accessed like this

```
system.file("extdata", "myTextFile.csv", package="MyPackage")
```

For an example of this solution, have a look at the [`EBImage`](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/EBImage.html) package, which contains a number of non-standard files in the form of images. Like your text files, they cannot be loaded with `data()`, so instead

```
system.file("images", "lena-color.png", package="EBImage")
```

is used in the examples of `?readImage` and similar.

Comment: Thank you a lot Backlin! This seemed to me a good idea, I just tried it, full of hope, but again a problem... 
When doing `R CMD check`, it creates a MyPackage.Rcheck directory right? In this directory, there is no longer the "texts" subdirectory that I created. So that, when I'm searching for my raw files with `system.file()`, it fails... 
In MyPackage.Rcheck, I only see: data, help, html, Meta and R.

Comment: That's strange, it works perfectly for me. I build it before I check it though, so try and see if that works. I see the `texts` directory both in `MyPackage_X-X-X.tar.gz` and in `MyPackage.Rcheck/00_pkg_src/MyPackage`.

Comment: I just tried the /inst/texts + `system.file()` method you mention, it seems to work !! I'm going to do more checks but I think it works fine ! Thank you so much for helping me ! Whatsmore I now understand better what is the "inst" subdirectory for.

Comment: Hi, I just wanted to add that someone from the R-help mailing list just answered me to do exactly the same thing, but naming the folder `./inst/extdata` as suggested in the 1.1.6 section of "Writing R Extensions". I read it several times without understand it well ! Thank you again everyone.